# Как сгенерировать файл docx в браузере на клиенте?

Tags: javascript, docx

Есть ли библиотека с помощью которой можно генерировать файлы docx на клиенте, без node js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, [docx.js](https://docx.js.org)

документация - https://docx.js.org/api/

```js
const generate = () => {
  const doc = new Document();

  const paragraph = new Paragraph("Hello World");
  const text1 = new TextRun("Foo Bar").bold();
  const text2 = new TextRun("Foo Bar").tab().bold();
  
  paragraph.addRun(text1);
  paragraph.addRun(text2);
  doc.addParagraph(paragraph);

  const packer = new Packer();

  packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => saveAs(blob, "example.docx"));
}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', generate);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/docx@4.0.0/build/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.js"></script>

<button type="button">Click to generate document</button>
```